# How to add dom with no directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How can I add dom with Angularjs without using a directive. Take it on my word that I cannot use a directive in this situation. Right now I'm adding dom using jQuery but I can't find a way to recompile it so that Angularjs knows how to deal with it. I would prefer to add dom using Angularjs because I think it would be easier to compile it that way, but I really don't know. After adding dom, how can I compile it without controllers. All I have is a registered app module.

An example of what I'm trying to do is in this jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/p437P/

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

var testCtrl = function($scope) {
    $scope.bool = {};
    $scope.bool.state = false;
};

app.controller('testCtrl',['$scope',testCtrl]);

setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('body').append('<div ng-controller="testCtrl"><p ng-show="bool.state">Hi</p></div>')
},500);
```

Comment: what does "add dom" mean? Add an element I am assuming?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code?

Comment: I think we need more context. I think you're asking for the answer to the wrong solution.

Comment: Explain why you cannot use a directive, we can't just take peoples word on things otherwise we could possibly miss something when trying to solve the problem. And as Rob says show some code so we know exactly what you want.

Comment: So what you are wanting is to dynamically add a controller element?

Comment: @Patrick. yes I want to dynamically add controllers and directives. I'm building a plugin that doesn't require the user to know angularjs to use it. You simply include my src and thats it. The plugin does the rest.

Comment: So you want a plugin that includes itself and bootstraps itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with angularjs just fine. With some help with ng-include and lazy loading.

For instance i have a controller (ModulesCtrl) that loads in modules (other controllers)

ModulesCtrl

```
app.controller('ModulesCtrl',['$rootScope','$scope',function ModulesCtrl($rootScope,$scope) {
   $scope.modules = [];
   $scope.data = {
      modules:[]
   };

   //Called after lazy loading the controllers js file 
   //otherwise you will get undefined function errors etc
   function addModule(){
      $scope.data.modules.push({
         template:'/templates/modules/test.template',
         settings:{name:"Test"}
      });
   }
}]);
```

ModulesCtrl Element

```
<div ng-controller="ModulesCtrl" ng-position="top">
   <div ng-repeat="module in data.modules" ng-include src="module.template"></div>
</div>
```

test.template

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  this is a test template
</div>
```

Now adding them in like this requires to do lazy loading so:

Snippets from: http://ify.io/lazy-loading-in-angularjs/

```
(function()
{
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.config(function($routeProvider, $controllerProvider, $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide)
    {
        app.controllerProvider = $controllerProvider;
        app.compileProvider    = $compileProvider;
        app.routeProvider      = $routeProvider;
        app.filterProvider     = $filterProvider;
        app.provide            = $provide;

        // Register routes with the $routeProvider
    });
})();
```

The lazy loaded controller would have to look like:

```
angular.module('app').controllerProvider.register('SomeLazyController', ['$scope'],function($scope)
{
    $scope.key = '...';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never, ever do dom manipulation outside of a directive, and you never need to. However, since you've convinced yourself otherwise:

```
//inject the $compile service into the controller
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
  //create the markup
  var $x = $('<p>{{foo}}</p>');
  $('body').append($x);
  //$compile it with the scope
  $compile($x)($scope);
});
```

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/iGUCofU/1/edit)**

Based on your update:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

var testCtrl = function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = 'See, I loaded!';
};

app.controller('testCtrl',['$scope',testCtrl]);

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      template: '<div ng-controller="testCtrl">{{foo}}</div>'
    };
});
```

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/iGUCofU/3/edit)**

Comment: This still uses jQuery, which is fine since he has it already. But if you didn't have it, you could replace the markup line with `var $x = angular.element('<p>{{foo}}</p>');`

Comment: @JonathanRowny of course, but he said he is doing the dom manipulation with jQuery. I am emphasizing that this is all wrong. I just answered it because I could.

Comment: The problem is that I am building a plugin that assumes the user doesn't know angularjs and doesn't want to know angularjs to use it. I don't have any controllers and I don't want to make the user add in the directives themselves. Controllers and directive are being added through jquery dom, then hopefully recompiled. I'm trying to figure out how to recompile it.

Comment: Why would the user have to add it? Why not just include it in your plugin's source?

Comment: @Mr.Student I still have no clue what you're talking about, but I remade your demo with a directive and no jQuery.

Comment: The plug-in src is pure js.

Comment: @Mr.Student Sorry, I have no idea what you're trying to do. If you really want to take everything outside of angular entirely (then what's the point of using Angular?!) then learn from my first example. cache a reference to `$compile` and `$scope` and then use them wherever you want.

Comment: The second answer led me to the answer. I was not understanding controllers thoroughly. I thought you could only have a valid controller if it was declared on some html with ng-controller directive.